# How can I make this accordion collapsed by default?

Tags: javascript, accordion

I'd like to use the javascript that W3C provides [here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/accordion/examples/accordion/) for an accordion. My problem is that the panels are expanded by default. I would like them to be collapsed when the page loads, and I can't figure out how to change it.

javascript:

```
'use strict';

      class Accordion {
        constructor(domNode) {
          this.rootEl = domNode;
          this.buttonEl = this.rootEl.querySelector('button[aria-expanded]');

          const controlsId = this.buttonEl.getAttribute('aria-controls');
          this.contentEl = document.getElementById(controlsId);

          this.open = this.buttonEl.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true';

          // add event listeners
          this.buttonEl.addEventListener('click', this.onButtonClick.bind(this));
        }

        onButtonClick() {
          this.toggle(!this.open);
        }

        toggle(open) {
          // don't do anything if the open state doesn't change
          if (open === this.open) {
            return;
          }

          // update the internal state
          this.open = open;

          // handle DOM updates
          this.buttonEl.setAttribute('aria-expanded', `${open}`);
          if (open) {
            this.contentEl.removeAttribute('hidden');
          } else {
            this.contentEl.setAttribute('hidden', '');
          }
        }

        // Add public open and close methods for convenience
        open() {
          this.toggle(true);
        }

        close() {
          this.toggle(false);
        }
      }

      // init accordions
      const accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion h3');
      accordions.forEach((accordionEl) => {
        new Accordion(accordionEl);
      });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="accordionGroup" class="accordion">
      <h3>
        <button type="button"
                aria-expanded="false"
                class="accordion-trigger"
                aria-controls="sect1"
                id="accordion1id">
          <span class="accordion-title">
            Section 1
            <span class="accordion-icon"></span>
          </span>
        </button>
      </h3>
      <div id="sect1"
           role="region"
           aria-labelledby="accordion1id"
           class="accordion-panel">
        <div>
          <div class="accordion-content">
            Section 1 content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I made sure that aria-expanded="false", but it's still expanded when the page loads.

Comment: make sure all the `aria-expanded` attributes of `button`s are set to `false`

Comment: @Yarin_007 Thanks for the advice. I tried that, and for some reason it's not working. I updated my question with my HTML

Comment: you need the `hidden` attribute too (on div#sect1 in your example) not sure why its not being added by the constructor though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the code it doesn't add the hidden state for you, so you'd either have to manually add it, or use something like the following

```
constructor(domNode) {
    this.rootEl = domNode;
    this.buttonEl = this.rootEl.querySelector('button[aria-expanded]');

    const controlsId = this.buttonEl.getAttribute('aria-controls');
    this.contentEl = document.getElementById(controlsId);

    this.open = this.buttonEl.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true';

    // make sure hidden elements are actually hidden
    if (!this.open && !this.contentEl.getAttribute("hidden")) { 
        this.contentEl.setAttribute("hidden", "")
    }

    // add event listeners
    this.buttonEl.addEventListener('click', this.onButtonClick.bind(this));
}
```

**update**

checking if the accordion is closed before adding the hidden attribute avoids conflicting states.

if `hidden` is set, and `aria-expanded` is also set, or the opposite state, you will have to press the button twice. the first press syncs the attributes, and the second actually does the action you wanted.

Comment: that worked! Is there a benefit to use that over simply this.contentEl.setAttribute('hidden', '');

Comment: yes. screensreaders :) they will not navigate / tell the user hidden content

Comment: yeah, it helps to make sure the attributes used to track the state match up